# EPPlus: Detect and deal with "number stored as text"

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

We read in an Excel spreadsheet using the EPPlus library and get various cell values.

One problem that may occur is when certain cell values are "number stored as text". We can ask users to try not to use spreadsheets with this warning, but I'd like to deal with it on my end if I can without polluting my code too badly.

When reading a cell value with "number stored as text" we see the following:

```
int foo = ws.Cells[row, column].GetValue<int>(); // foo comes out as 0
string bar = Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[row, column].Value); // bar comes out as "7"
```

Ideally I would like a way to read all values correctly without having to parse a string for potentially every single cell in the spreadsheet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EPPLUS how to know the format of the Worksheet cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591763/epplus-how-to-know-the-format-of-the-worksheet-cell)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to mark this as accepted because it does not actually answer my question, so if anyone does work out how to detect "number stored as text" then please answer and I'll accept you.

In the end I replaced `.GetValue<int>()`, etc. with a method call instead. You could even turn it into an extension method depending on your purposes for greater readability.

The method looks like this:

```
    private int GetInt(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (value is double)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
        else if (value is string)
        {
            var intValue = 0;
            Int32.TryParse((string)value, out intValue);
            return intValue;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected value type.");
        }
    }
```

and I call it thusly:

```
int foo = GetInt(ws.Cells[row, column].Value); // foo comes out as 7
```